# MySQL transpose and calculate percentage

Tags: mysql

I wish to write some code in MySQL that will transpose the first column of a table to rows and fetch data from the second column on that same table to calculate the percentage result of a column in another table.

For example:

payroll_structure:

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| percentage | int(3)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

this is the first table which and I wish to fetch and transpose all the data in the `payroll.name` column into rows to form an header for a data table result.
also i wish to fetch all the data in the percentage column and then use them to calculate the percentage results of another table column.

salaries:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| amount   | double(19,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| staff_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

If I run this code

```
SELECT staff.id
     , staff.fullname AS StaffName
     , (SELECT payroll_structure.percentage 
          FROM payroll_structure 
         WHERE payroll_structure.name = 'Basic') / 100 * salaries.amount AS Basic
     , (SELECT payroll_structure.percentage 
          FROM payroll_structure 
         WHERE payroll_structure.name = 'Housing') / 100 * salaries.amount AS Housing 
  FROM staff
     , salaries 
 WHERE staff.id = salaries.staff_id 
 ORDER 
    BY salaries.staff_id ASC 
 LIMIT 5;
```

I get this result:

```
+----+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+
| id | StaffName               | Basic       | Housing     |
+----+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | Staff 1                 | 120000.0000 | 100000.0000 |
|  2 | Staff 2                 | 105000.0000 |  87500.0000 |
|  3 | Staff 3                 |  90000.0000 |  75000.0000 |
|  4 | Staff 4                 |  90000.0000 |  75000.0000 |
|  5 | Staff 5                 |  75000.0000 |  62500.0000 |
+----+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

And looking at my code:

```
(SELECT payroll_structure.percentage FROM payroll_structure WHERE payroll_structure.name = 'Basic') / 100 * salaries.amount AS Basic, 

(SELECT payroll_structure.percentage FROM payroll_structure WHERE payroll_structure.name = 'Housing') / 100 * salaries.amount AS Housing
```

Is there anyway the code can be written to generate the values in `payroll.name` column with WHERE clause in such that whenever new record is inserted in the `payroll_structure.name` column and `payroll_structure.percentage` it reflect automatically as a result.

For example let's assume Transport is added to `payroll_structure` and `payroll_structure.name = 'Transport' and`payroll_structure.percentage = '20'` to be divided by 100 as written in the code

```
SELECT staff.id
     , staff.fullname AS StaffName
     , (SELECT payroll_structure.percentage 
          FROM payroll_structure 
         WHERE payroll_structure.name = 'Basic') / 100 * salaries.amount AS Basic
     , (SELECT payroll_structure.percentage 
          FROM payroll_structure 
         WHERE payroll_structure.name = 'Housing') / 100 * salaries.amount AS Housing
     , (SELECT payroll_structure.percentage 
          FROM payroll_structure 
         WHERE payroll_structure.name = 'Transport') / 100 * salaries.amount AS Transport 
  FROM staff
     , salaries 
 WHERE staff.id = salaries.staff_id 
 ORDER 
    BY salaries.staff_id ASC 
 LIMIT 5;`

+----+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| id | StaffName               | Basic       | Housing      |   Transport |
+----+-------------------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
|  1 | Staff 1                 | 120000.0000 | 100000.0000  | 80000.0000  |
|  2 | Staff 2                 | 105000.0000 |  87500.0000  |  71500.0000 |
|  3 | Staff 3                 |  90000.0000 |  75000.0000  |  60000.0000 |
|  4 | Staff 4                 |  90000.0000 |  75000.0000  |  60000.0000 |
|  5 | Staff 5                 |  75000.0000 |  62500.0000  |  1500.0000  |
+----+-------------------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Is there a way to write the code rather than doing the same thing for all the result in `payroll_structure.name` and `payroll_structure.percentage`

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please help me with the question!